# Loading a webpage into an Android App

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview

I'm working on an android app and I want to be able to load a webpage in the application. I've browsed around the internet for a while and can't seem to get it just right. I know that my internet connection is established, as I can use my browser. I'm new to android development and learning as I go, so any elaboration would be amazing. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
      }
}
Button btnBack;
WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    openURL();
}

 /** Opens the URL in a browser */
private void openURL() {
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webview.requestFocus();
}
}
```

and my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/rlayout1"
    android:id="@+id/rlayout2">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what happens when I run the application:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wow guys, sorry if this is spammed but I just found a forum explanation that I didn't see before. Android requires internet permissions in an app for it to access the internet. I thought that it would give me a permissions exception, but instead it just doesn't load it. here's what I added to the xml manifest for it to work correctly

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Again, sorry I feel really stupid for not knowing about this. You'd think the console would print some sort of security/permission exception

Comment: Yes, there is permission exception in logcat output.